# Using service layer in Repository Pattern for "Standard" business logic / Utility methods?

Tags: c#, architecture, repository-pattern

I am using a standard repository pattern with a service layer which calls the data layer..

I have some Utility classes i.e. one that deals with Sending email (method name = SendMail)

Where is the correct place to put this?

Inside the service layer as a method called SendMail

hence I have CustomerService which calls CustomerRepository

So in this case i create a new UtilityService which will hold all the business logic for utility classes i.e. Sendmail

Little bit confused where i should put these

Any help really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of your sevice layer as having two levels first is a coordination / aggregation layer that calls the second layer which is the individual services, this will include the utility service.

In some cases this can be overkill since you get a lot of pass-through services.

Comment: thank you very much fro your reply, so are you saying that i should then setup a new class in my Service called UtilityService (similar to my customerService etc) which can hold my Sendmail and things like that..

Hence from my CustomerService i can call to my repository and "ALSO" call my UtilityService from my CustomerService if i require SendMail?

Naming conventions: I presume UtilityService is a good standard or should i even be more specific and call this EmailService 

Maybe getting to deep there?

Comment: Yes, the customer service will call the Email service and the repository. You could call it EmailHelper to differenciate it from a service.

Comment: And to add to the above if you wrap the call to the repository + emailer in an TransactionScope if either of them fail then the whole process is roled back, not leaving the anyhting in an invalid state...